# Connect to a project server when opening MS Project

Tags: macros, vbscript, ms-project

I have a vbscript that checks to see if MS Project is open. If it's already open it runs a macro if not it should open Project then run the macro. It works fine if Project is already open. If project isn't open the script successfully opens and runs the macro but fails half way through. Basically it fails because the macro that is being called opens files from project server. even with my default account set to the Project server url and 'when starting' set to 'choose my default account' it still fails.

vbscript to open & run macro:

```
dim pjApp

on error resume next
set pjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")

    if err.Number = 0 then
    pjApp.Visible = True    
    pjApp.macro "testsave"
    else 
    Set pjApp = CreateObject("MSProject.Application") 
    pjApp.Visible = True 
    pjApp.macro "testsave"
    end if
Set pjApp = Nothing
```

Is there a way of forcing it to connect to the project server site when Project opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the real issue:

> Basically it fails because the macro that is being called opens files from **project server**.

In order to automate MS Project and have it open to a project server, you need to launch winproj.exe using a command-line switch as follows:

**VBScript**

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim pjApp 
Set pjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim ProjServer
    ProjServer = Chr(34) & "enter project server name here" & Chr(34)
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "winproj /s " & ProjServer, 1, True
    Set objShell = Nothing 
    WScript.Sleep 5000
    Set pjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
End If
pjApp.Macro "testsave"
```

The code first checks to see if MS Project is already open and if so, uses that instance. Otherwise it uses the shell command to open to a specific project server.

Note: Update sleep value as necessary to give MS Project enough time to open before trying to get a reference to it.

**VBA version**

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim pjApp As MSProject.Application
Set pjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Dim ProjServer As String
    ProjServer = Chr$(34) & "enter project server name here" & Chr$(34)
    Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Winproj.exe /s " & ProjServer, vbNormalFocus
    Do While pjApp Is Nothing
        DoEvents
        Set pjApp = GetObject(, "MSProject.Application")
    Loop
End If
pjApp.Macro "testsave"
```

Note: Update the path to Winproj.exe as necessary.

Documentation for command-line switches seems to have been removed from Microsoft's site. Here's a page that still provides the documentation:
[Using Command-line switches for Project](https://integent.com/using-command-line-switches-for-project-2007/). Briefly:

- /s "URL"
- /u "username"
- /p "password"
- filename
- -ProjectProfiles

Comment: Rachel, thanks for your response. I’ve tried your code. It works fine if project is open. Unfortunately I still get issues if project isn't open. On the line 'ProjServer = Chr(34) & "enter project server name here" & Chr(34)' if I add the url with quotes and https://  project opens but the macro doesn't fire. If I use https:// with no quotes, I get a vbscript compilation error. If I use neither quotes nor https:// (i.e. just url) project opens but the macro doesn't fire. Finally, if I use just quotes and url (e.g. "projectserver/pwa")  project opens but I get a 'could not connect to server'.

Comment: @kagey, If the macro isn't firing but Project does connect to the server, increase the sleep value to give the application more time to open before the code continues. If it is not connecting to the server, verify the project server name (in Project 2010, go to File, Info and hover over the link shown below "Go to Project Web App"); enter that text between the quotes in the ProjServer = line.

Comment: I had to crank the sleep command up to 15k! thanks so much Rachel. all working now.

Answer (score 0):

In place of pjApp.macro try:

```
pjApp.Appllication.Run "testsave"
```

I know that it is weird that the .macro version works for the code above it; however, it is still worth a shot.  This code should also work for both places where you are using the .macro method.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Sorry, I should've mentioned (I'm new to this), the macro is on the Global.mpt template as the purpose of it is opening a list of projects from project server and saving them to a network folder.

Comment: Thank you for that information.  I have edited my answer accordingly.