# How to load "Project Server" project with Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject C#

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, ms-project, project-server

How can I problematically tell MS Project to load a Project Server project using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject in .NET C#?

I know how to load an MPP file, using the code below. But how do you load a project from Project Server or Project Web Access?

I'm using the code below to load an MPP file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();
app.FileOpenEx(sMPPPathname, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    MSProject.PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadWrite,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Does it have to be done using the Interop assembly? Project Server provide a couple of different ways to interact using web services and CSOM API's. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms504195.aspx

Comment: Yes, Interop. This is an existing app that just needs one little enhancement: to open Project Server and PWA projects (in addition to the existing MPP files it already opens).

Answer (score 0):

The FileOpenEx command works the same for Project Server, you just need to use this syntax for the filename argument: "<>\ProjectName".

MS Project Object Model: [FileOpenEx Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867007.aspx)

Comment: Just to confirm, I assume the angle brackets and backslash are part of the syntax, and are used to signal MSP that the filename is not an MPP on disk, but instead a PWA or Project Server project, true? So I could open my PWA project with a "filename" like this: <>\MyPwaProjectname.  Is this documented somewhere? This does seem odd, since the projectname doesn't include a distinct location such as https://myserver/myprojects/myfile. How does this syntax tell MSP which server to fetch the project from?

Comment: @RayWhite When the user opens the MS Project application, they connect to a Project Server, so it is already specified. If your application is launching Project, see this post for how to connect to a project server: [stackoverflow.com/questions/24121106...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121106/connect-to-a-project-server-when-opening-ms-project), adapt to C# as necessary.

Comment: Users don't open MSP. I use Microsoft.Office.Interop to open it. So how does the "<>\ProjectName" parameter choose the correct PWA server? I've learned that "<ODBCDataSourceName>\ProjectName" might work. Should I create an ODBC data source to connect to PWA?

Comment: Regardless of whether it's a user or automation that opens Project Pro the application connects to a Project Server upon initiation. Project 2010, requires command line switches to select a Project Server (otherwise it defaults to Computer). Project 2013 opens with the default account (profile). Hopefully 2016 does the same. If you're using 2013 or 2016, set the default account to the correct server (you do this in the application). If you need to switch between different PWAs then use the command line method.

Comment: An alternative to command line switches for 2013 and later would be to use a reg file to update the default profile before launching the Project application.