# Open PWA project in MS Project as read-only

Tags: ms-project

I am looking to start winproj.exe with a PWA Server URL and a project name. However, I want the project to open in read-only (not checked out) state. How can I do this?

So far I have `WINPROJ.EXE /s <pwaurl> "<>\projectname"`

This opens the project from PWA fine...however, its checked out. Is there a readonly switch or something?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a script rather than the command line directly... If you follow the approach described in the answer to this question: [Connect to a project server when opening MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121106/connect-to-a-project-server-when-opening-ms-project), this will get you an instance of MS Project connected to your PWA server. You should then be able to use the `FileOpenEx` method (as described here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867007.aspx) to open the project using the `ReadOnly` argument:

```
pjApp.Application.FileOpenEx "<>\projectname", True
```

(Unfortunately I don't have a PWA instance or Project Professional to verify this - good luck!)

Comment: I was able to do it as such - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\WINPROJ.EXE" /s http://pwaurl "C:\local.mpp". Once opened I ran a macro within local.mpp to open mpp files within PWA and this worked just fine.