# Connect to specific Project Server Site and Project using MS Project Object Model

Tags: c#, ms-project

Note: I have resolved the error issue with `winproj.exe` opening throwing errors.  This issue is no longer an issue for me.

I have essentially solved most of this issue by updating the property Embedded `IntroOp` Types to false in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject` in Visual Studio which has allowed me to use the `ApplicationClass` process I have inserted the new code.

The only problem I have now is when I open up `winproj.exe`:

```
var objProcess = Process.Start(@"winproj.exe", " / s " + OnlinePWA
```

It throws an errors with a file not found which stops the process until I cancel those out and then opens the project.  If anyone has any input on opening winproj.exe and suppressing errors please let me know.

Thanks

```cs
public static List<FromTaskLinksClient> GetProjectTaskLinks(string OnlinePWA,
    string UserName, string Password, List<string> Projects, string OnPrem)
{
    string PWAInstance = OnlinePWA.Replace("https://", "");
    string[] PWAInstance2 = PWAInstance.Split('/');
    int i = PWAInstance2.Count() - 1;
    string PWAInstance3 = PWAInstance2[i];
    SetDefaultPWAInstance.SetInstanceToYes(PWAInstance3);
    var objProcess = Process.Start(@"winproj.exe", " / s " + OnlinePWA);
    List <FromTaskLinksClient> fromTaskLinksClients =
        new List<FromTaskLinksClient>();
    foreach (var inproject in Projects)
    {
        ApplicationClass objProject = new ApplicationClass();
        objProject.Visible = false;
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object oFile = @"<>\" + inproject.ToString();
        object oReadOnly = true;
        object oFormat = "MSProject.mpp";
        object oUserID = UserName.ToString();
        object oDatabasePassword = Password.ToString();
        objProject.DisplayAlerts = false;
        objProject.FileOpen(oFile, oReadOnly, PjMergeType.pjDoNotMerge,
            oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oUserID, oDatabasePassword,
            oFormat, oMissing, PjPoolOpen.pjPoolReadOnly, oMissing, oMissing,
            oMissing, oMissing);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Project project =
            objProject.ActiveProject;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Task task in project.Tasks)
        {
            if (task.Predecessors.Contains("+") ||
                task.Predecessors.Contains("-"))
            {
                FromTaskLinksClient fromTaskClientLinks =
                    new FromTaskLinksClient();
                string Name = task.Name;
                fromTaskClientLinks.ProjectName = inproject.ToString();
                fromTaskClientLinks.TaskPredValue = task.Predecessors;
                fromTaskClientLinks.TaskPred_Id = Guid.Parse(task.Guid);
                fromTaskClientLinks.TaskPred_Name = task.Name;
                fromTaskClientLinks.TaskPred_OutLineLevel = task.OutlineLevel;
                fromTaskClientLinks.TaskPred_OutLineNumber = task.OutlineNumber;
                fromTaskClientLinks.ProjectId = Guid.Empty;
                fromTaskLinksClients.Add(fromTaskClientLinks);    
            }
        }
        objProject.Quit(PjSaveType.pjDoNotSave);
    }
    SetDefaultPWAInstance.SetInstanceToNo(PWAInstance3);
    return fromTaskLinksClients;
}
```

I expect to be able to access project and task data to make updates to them.  Again CSOM does not allow updates to predecessors with fs+ x days. I would have to use the MS Project object model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to a project server when opening MS Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121106/connect-to-a-project-server-when-opening-ms-project)

Comment: Thanks Rachel.  Do you happen to have a c# option for this.  The VBA option isn't going to work for me.  What I'm seeing is my objproject opens the default which is my pwasales instance and I want it to open my pwa instance.  I saw your reference to changing registry values prior to opening using the interop.msproject application object but was hoping I could just set the profile defaults programattically.  Fyi I sent you a connect on linked in to discuss this.

Comment: I've resolved most of this by doing the following:  First you have to go into the properties of Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject and change the Embedded Interop Types to false.  I've posted the new code above but still have an issue when winproj.exe kicks off.  It throws error messages saying "Project cannot open this file" because I'm not specifying a file until later in the code.  I now just need to suppress the winproj.exe open error.  Any thoughts

Comment: There should not be a space in the middle of the command-line switch: it should read `" /s " + OnlinePWA`, and I'm not sure there should be a comma after winproj.exe—try `@"winproj.exe /s " + OnlinePWA`.

Comment: Thanks Rachel, I discovered exactly that and implemented that fix.  The only problem I'm having now is I publish my web application which is hosted on my azure tenant and when I run it live it won't open the desktop project professional application.  I'm thinking I have to figure out how to allow a web application that is running on a cloud server access to my desktop project professional application to open and process an update to a project.  Any suggestions from anyone that has opened an office app from an external web app would be helpful

Comment: Rachel - fyi you do need the comma when using C#